# Insert only to specific fields in formModel in django

Tags: python, django

I have a django model and its corresponding form to insert into and read value from a table with three columns in database. My requirement is I only need to insert in to say two  column using form, leaving the third column which is a date field. But I have a requirement to read all three column to display it in html in later time. When I use exclude in the form it works good for the html part but when trying to save the form using form.save(), it tries to insert null in the the third column and raise error. Can anybody please help me to omit the third column completely while saving the form.

```
Class sales(models.Model)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quantity=models.FloatField()
    sale_date=models.DateField()
```

I was looking for a solution where one override the save() to omit this field before saving. But I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sale_date shall have `auto_add=True` attribute in the model. so Django sets the value of the date to the current date automatically.

Comment: But I dont want to set current date. Actually that field will be filled only on the date the product is sold. I want to completely leave that field for later date updation. Thanks for replying @Mohamed ElKalioby.

Comment: Then you shall allow the sale_date to be null by adding `null=True` and `blank=True`

Comment: I am sorry , I shall give you the full picture. The database is existing DB with another front end. I am using django for some backend updation and reporting. Actually the date field is set to sysdate by default in the db itself,  that I cant change. That is the issue. Now I have to update few sales record using django. Thats the reason I want to omit it. I understand I can create model omitting the date field, but then I cant use it to display records  including the date in report.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider not overriding the save method at all, and handling how and what you want to save in your view logic. For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

if request.method == 'POST':
   form = MyForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid(): 
      new_object = form.save(commit=False)
      if commit: # or some logical check, if needed
          new_object.sale_date = timezone.now().date()
      new_object.save()
```

You can also be explicit about your fields in a save method:

```
.save(update_fields=['your_field_name', 'your_other_field_name'])
```

...which will cause django to only write to the fields you have declared.  It's hard to know what you're trying to achieve with the `sale_date` field, but you may want to make it nullable and blank, like so:

```
sale_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

...after which you could update it only if null, for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
from django import forms
from .models import sales

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = sales
        fields = ['product_name', 'quantity']  # Specify only the required fields

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(YourForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # Skip saving the sale_date column
        # You can set other values ​​if needed
        # For example: instance.sale_date = some_value
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: But If I dont add the saledate field in fields = ['product_name', 'quantity'] , then how can I use this model to read and display data in the html. Thanks for replying ..@ruslan rzaev

Comment: Please format your code correctly and remove unnecessary comments